# How to dynamically access an attribute of an object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, object

I have a data that looks like this

```
data = [(u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 59L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0), 449L), (u'Del', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 0L), (u'Bom', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 0, 0), 45L)]
```

I am using `pandas` to do some data wrangling. Now I need to get a list of dates from the data in certain formats like `hour`, `month`, `year` etc. So to extract dates from the data in `month`, this is what I do

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dates = df[1].dt.month.values.tolist()
```

So I get a list of months. But in the method `df[1].dt.year.values.tolist()`, I want to assign the granularity dynamically ie it could either be `dt.month` or `dt.year` based on the variable value.

Say I have a variable called `granularity_val`

So if `granularity_val = 'year'`, I should do

```
dates = df[1].dt.year.values.tolist()
```

Similarly if `granularity_val = 'month'`, I should do

```
dates = df[1].dt.month.values.tolist()
```

So I tried doing something like this

```
granularity_val = 'year'
dates = df[1].dt.granularity_val.values.tolist()
```

But it throws an error like below

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'granularity_val'
```

I understand it is trying to treat the variable as an attribute of `dt` object of `pandas`. So how do I make python understand that it needs to treat `granularity_val` not as an attribute but as a variable value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to reference any attribute by string

```
getattr(df[1].dt, granularity_val).values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr) for get attribute and for pandas 0.24+ instead `values` use [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: pd.date_range('2010-01-02', periods=5)})

granularity_val = 'month'
dates = getattr(df[1].dt, granularity_val).to_numpy().tolist()
print (dates)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

```
granularity_val = 'year'
dates = getattr(df[1].dt, granularity_val).to_numpy().tolist()
print (dates)
[2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010]
```

Comment: @SouvikRay so your pandas version is under 0.24+

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do using [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
granularity_val = 'year'

match = {'year': '%Y', 'month': '%m', 'day': '%d'}

date = df.date.dt.strftime(match[granularity_val])

print(date)
['01', '01', '01', '01', '01']
```

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=5))
```

Answer (score 0):

For an example, let's use python's turtle.

```
import turtle 
t = turtle.Turtle();
t.color('red','blue');
```

So this sets our turtle to the color red, and it's border to blue. Now, let's say later on in the code we would want turtle's color. We can use this code.

```
print({t.color()});
```

In turtle, this will give us a very odd set:
`set([('red','blue')])`
But, in most other cases, this will give us better feedback.